# Can't delete azure storage queue message after it has been updated (Message not found)

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-queues, azure-node-sdk

Used two different libraries for node.js, `azure-storage` and `fast-azure-storage`, to the same result.

Here's what I do:

1. Create a message with default settings - ok.
2. Get message from a queue - ok.
3. Update message to reset `visibility timeout` - ok.
4. Delete message after processing - Error: MessageNotFound.

If I skip updating, everything goes smooth.

So what I'm doing wrong?

P.S. Tried to analyse the http traffic, it seems to fully comply with the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh452234.aspx). Like this is an Azure internal problem?
Maybe someone has any experience updating messages using other language libraries? Too inconvenient to `curl` that service due to calculation of the auth header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the document [Delete Message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179347.aspx) mentions, the function requires the parameter `popreceipt` which is returned by [Get Messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179474.aspx) or [Update Message](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh452234.aspx) operation.

And after update message operation, the `popreceipt` of this message changes. So if you code snippet looks like this:

```
queueSvc.getMessages('myqueue', function(error, result, response){
  if(!error){
    // Messages retreived
    for(var index in result){
      var message = result[0];
      queueSvc.updateMessage('myqueue', message.messageid, message.popreceipt, 0, {messageText: 'new text'}, function(error, result, response){
          if(!error){
            // Message updated successfully
            console.log('result: '+JSON.stringify(result));
            console.log(message.popreceipt)
            queueSvc.deleteMessage('myqueue', message.messageid, message.popreceipt, function(error, response){
                if(!error){
                    console.log(response);
                  // Message deleted
                }else{
                    console.log(error);
                }
              });
          }else{
            console.log(error);
          }
        });
    }
  }
});
```

You will occur your issue, and you can monitor in cmdlet, we found the  `popreceipt` changed after update operation.

So if you need to delete the message after update operation, you have to leverage the `result` object which is the new message object after updating.E.g.

```
queueSvc.deleteMessage('myqueue', result.messageid, result.popreceipt, function(error, response){
            if(!error){
                console.log(response);
              // Message deleted
            }else{
                console.log(error);
            }
          });
```

Comment: Thanks, Gary! That was my guess.
I was mislead by the `fast-azure-storage`, which ignores the new `popreceipt`. And the official module is really very slow with the queues.

Comment: Btw, it is already implemented in the `fast-azure-storage` module.

Comment: Yes, it seems the `updateMessage` function will return the new `popreceipt` from the [source code](https://github.com/taskcluster/fast-azure-storage/blob/master/lib/queue.js#L897)

Comment: Yeah, actually that's there after my pull-request based on your answer here :)

Answer (score 0):

What did you mean by "Update message to reset visibility timeout"? Did you set the invisibility timeout to zero? If so, the error in step 4 is expected because you're not allowed to [delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dd179347.aspx) the messages which are visible currently.

Comment: No I meant to set it to 30 seconds again.